# How to refer node created by one template in XSLT at runtime from the calling template?

Tags: xslt

I have split one string `key6='||1-LIW-3324|1-LIW-3325|1-LIW-3326|1-LIW-3327|1-LIW-4232'` with separator `'|'` thru one template named `StringSplit`. 
I have called this `StringSplit` template from another template. So each split value is stored in `SeparatedLineItems`.
Now I want to refer each split node(`SeparatedLineItems`) in the calling template and want to compare each separated/split node with another variable . How can i do it.

Here is the code.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="check3">
        <xsl:value-of select="1-LIW-3"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <myProj>
    <xsl:call-template name="StringSplit">
            <xsl:with-param name="val" select="$key6"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <!--here I want to compare "SeperatedLineItems" with $check3 -->                   
    <!--<xsl:variable name="con"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="contains($key6,$check3)"/> 
    </xsl:variable>-->        
    </myProj>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="StringSplit">
    <xsl:param name="val" select="$key6"/>
    <!-- do a check to see if the input string (still) has a "|" in it -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($val, '|')">
            <!-- pull out the value of the string before the "|" delimiter -->
            <SeperatedLineItems>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($val, '|')"/>
            </SeperatedLineItems> 
            <!-- recursively call this template and pass in value AFTER the "|" delimiter -->
            <xsl:call-template name="StringSplit">
                <xsl:with-param name="val" select="substring-after($val, '|')"/> 
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- if there is no more delimiter values, print out the whole string -->
            <SeperatedLineItems>
                <xsl:value-of select="$val"/>
            </SeperatedLineItems>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet demonstrates how to access the elements returned by calling a template ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="key6" select="'||1-LIW-3324|1-LIW-3325|1-LIW-3326|1-LIW-3327|1-LIW-4232'" />  

<xsl:template match="/">
Does my $key6 variable contain precisely '1-LIW-3'?
 <xsl:variable name="keys"> 
  <xsl:call-template name="StringSplit">
    <xsl:with-param name="val" select="$key6"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:choose> 
   <xsl:when test="msxsl:node-set($keys)/*[. = '1-LIW-3']">
    YES
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise> 
    NO
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="StringSplit">
  <xsl:param name="val" />
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains($val,'|')">
    <SeperatedLineItems>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($val,'|')" />
    </SeperatedLineItems>
    <xsl:variable name="remainder"> 
     <xsl:call-template name="StringSplit">
       <xsl:with-param name="val" select="substring-after($val,'|')" />
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($remainder)/*" /> 
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="$val != ''">
    <SeperatedLineItems>
      <xsl:value-of select="$val" />
    </SeperatedLineItems>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise> 
  </xsl:otherwise> 
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**To which the result is...**

```
Does my $key6 variable contain '1-LIW-3'?

    NO
```

**And here is the XSLT 2.0 equivalent...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="key6" select="'||1-LIW-3324|1-LIW-3325|1-LIW-3326|1-LIW-3327|1-LIW-4232'" />  

<xsl:template match="/">
Does my $key6 variable contain precisely '1-LIW-3'?
 <xsl:variable name="keys" select="tokenize($key6,'\|')" as="xs:string*" /> 
 <xsl:choose> 
   <xsl:when test="some $key in $keys satisfies ($key = '1-LIW-3')">
    YES
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise> 
    NO
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above makes the $keys variable a sequence of strings rather than elements containing strings. If you prefer elements, then you could use the following alternative. Although this alternative suffers from the disadvantage that it does not include the empty string items.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="key6" select="'||1-LIW-3324|1-LIW-3325|1-LIW-3326|1-LIW-3327|1-LIW-4232'" />  

<xsl:template match="/">
Does my $key6 variable contain precisely '1-LIW-3'?
 <xsl:variable name="keys" as="element()*" > 
  <xsl:analyze-string select="concat($key6,'|')" regex="([^\|]*)\|">
   <xsl:matching-substring>  
    <SeperatedLineItems>
     <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" />
    </SeperatedLineItems>
   </xsl:matching-substring>  
  </xsl:analyze-string> 
 </xsl:variable> 
 <xsl:choose> 
   <xsl:when test="$keys[. = '1-LIW-3']">
    YES
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise> 
    NO
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks for your answers. But the result i want is the exact match of 1-LIW-3. And 1-LIW-3 is not present in keys6. So the expected result i want from above is : Does my $key6 variable contain '1-LIW-3'?   NO

Comment: @hero_mca Ok. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Thansk Sean, now it is working but i did some modifications. It was not working with msxsl so i used xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" and then it worked. :)

Comment: Yes, how to get node-set() to work depends on which XSLT engine you are using.